# How to link my custom post type category to its respective archive in wordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, wp-list-categories

i have created my custom post type using `"types"` plugin and have displayed all my categories on a single page .now i want each category to link with its respective archive but couldn't found anything useful .
i have created link on categories like this :

```
 <?php
 foreach ( $categories as $cat ) {
      echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($cat->term_id).'">'.$cat->cat_name.'</a>';   
 ?>
     <div class="row">
           <div class="ct-divider"> </div>
     </div>

<?php 
}
?>
```

but this href link is good for going to default post categories but doesn't pick up the link for archive of custom post type...

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `get_term_link();` for example:

- [get_term_link();](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/)

use for Generate a permalink for a taxonomy term archive.

here is one example

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'category');
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'category').'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: i have written it like this : <?php
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'category');

foreach ($terms as $term) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->stateleague-pos-type, 'category').'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';

    ?>
<div class="row">
                            <div class="ct-divider"> </div>
                        </div>

<?php
}



?> but its not showing categories name ..

Comment: as per your code you want just term link right ? so use given function its easy to get link of category.!  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/

Comment: but no text appears on screen where should i click to chk whether it has a right link on it or not?